# Existence and Uniqueness - polynomial EDO

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wonder if it is to provide existence and uniqueness sufficient conditions for the equation $y'(t) = -a \, y^p$. Some conditions are simple to analyze: for $p=1$, the is only one solution and equal to $y(t) = y(0) \, e^{-a \, t}$. My master professor said the equation may have more than one solution for $p \in (0, 1)$, but I fail to understand. In my opinion, my doubt lays on one of the $\Longrightarrow$.

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{dy}{y^p} = \int dt + C \Longrightarrow \frac{y^{1-p}}{1-p} = -a \, t + C \Longrightarrow y = \left[(1-p)(-a \, t + C)\right]^{\frac{1}{1-p}} \end{equation}

I thank in advance and for the answers.

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do an analysis for $p=1/2$, to make things a bit more explicit.

As you've computed, if $y\ne 0$, (and this assumption is where the other solutions may be lost), we have
$$
y(t)=\frac14(-at+C)^2
$$
Now let's say we set $y(0)=0$, then $C=0$, and $y(t)=\frac{a^2}{4} t^2$ is a solution. But of course, the zero solution also solves the equation, with the initial condition $y(0)=0$. In fact, the situation is much worse, one can just delay "take off" of these parabolas, and build an infinite set of solutions, for $s\geq 0$, take $y(t)=0$ for $0\leq t<s$, then for $t\geq s$, take $y(t)=\frac{1}{4}(-at+as)^2$.

One can view this as just starting the integration in the separation of variables at the first point, named $s$, where $y\ne 0$.

Comment: A tricky question: since for $p = 1$, there is an unique solution, where does the discontinuity of solution lay? I mean, by continuity, there would have still a solution for $p \to 1^-$.

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto I'm not sure I follow. If you are discussing how the solutions depend on the parameter, yes there is a solution as we take $p\uparrow 1$, and it agrees with what you get by elementary methods: The (unique) solution to $y'=-ay$, $y(0)=0$ is $y\equiv 0$. But yes, it is tricky :)

Comment: The formal statement is: where does the $p \stackrel{!}{\geq} 1$ comes from?

Comment: @BrunoHenriquePeixoto the $p\geq 1$ requirement for uniqueness is a function of $-ay^p$ being Lipschitz (locally for $p>1$, globally for $p=1$) which guarantees a unique solution in the neighborhood (this is Picard's theorem). The trouble for $0<p<1$ is you lose the Lipschitz continuity. This leaves you with the possibility of many different solutions (you still have at least one, by a different existence theorem using only continuity). Indeed, that's what occurs.

Comment: Wonderful! I thank you sincerely, man!